# How do I get docker cloud (formerly tutum) and haproxy to use SSL?

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I just purchased an SSL Certificate. It came with 1 server certificate, 1 intermediate certificate and 1 root certificate.

I have my *.csr file and *.key used to create the certificates.

I am using Tutum with HAProxy and there is a SSL_CERT environment variable. I read the documentation but could not get it to work properly. How do I set this SSL_CERT environment variable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am the maintainer of the tutum/haproxy image. To use `SSL_CERT`, you need a file containing both your public certificate(`your.crt`) and private key(`your.key`). You can do as follows:

`cp your.key cert.pem
 cat your.crt >> cert.pem`

Then, you can run:
`awk 1 ORS='\\n' ~/cert.pem`.

Copy the output to `SSL_CERT`

Done

Comment: Yeah, this is what I figured out and was able to get things working. Thanks for writing the answer for others.

Comment: There might be a slight typo in that it's `cat your.crt >> cert.pem` not `.csr` which is the certificate signing file.

Comment: @yunspace yes. I have changed the name of the certificate. Thank you.

Comment: cannot get this to work.... copied the output of snakeoil files as above to env variable in apahche/php/unbuntu container (using docker-compose)... also tried putting it in env vars for haproxy (both with and without DEFAULT_)... I have also set vhost bit... any way I try this I cannot get it working :(

Comment: So it looks like it was just the VIRTUAL_HOST needed to proceed with https:// So proceed VIRTUAL_HOST with https and set SSL_CERT as per above in your linked application container. Happy boy :)

Comment: There is a good complete example here that worked for me: https://github.com/tutumcloud/haproxy/issues/130#issuecomment-174492191